# Cohomological dimension of $G \times G$

Tags: group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2320997/cohomological-dimension-of-direct-product), but asks a much simpler one:

Let $cd$ denote the cohomological dimension of a group, i.e. the minimal length of a projective resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ over the group ring.

Is is true for every group $G$ of finite cohomological dimension that 
$$cd(G \times G) \stackrel{?}{>} cd(G )$$

Comment: Yes, provided that $G$ is nontrivial; this will follow from the Kunneth formula, which should be in Brown's book "Cohomology of groups".

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Moishe. But the Kuenneth formula requires that the homology groups of $G$ are finitely generated, which requires some extra condition. The Kuenneth formula for group cohomology is not in Brown's book, just as an exercise without giving the formula, but it is contained in Chris Gerig's tremendously helpful answer to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75472/kuenneth-formula-for-group-cohomology-with-nontrivial-action-on-the-coefficient